# Custom JOptionPane. Reproduce JOptionPane behavior for own window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, joptionpane

I have noticed that u can not change the bar color of a JOptionPane, so i have decided to make my own window for iformation messages that fits to the style of my programm. Any solutions that can reproduce the behavior of a JOptionPane?

- Mainwindow not clickable when information window is open.
- Let Mainwindow shake when information window is open and you click somewhere else.
- Information window always over Mainwindow

Image of my mainwindow and the information window. Mainwindow (in the background should not be clickable when information window is open:

[Click me for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLqYG.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Information window is just a JDialog now.

```
    InfoMessage im = new InfoMessage();
    im.setModal(true);
    im.setVisible(true);
```

You can set a JDialog modal to true and it acts like a JOptionPane